# Signed package/apk crashes in NDK on a known device but not on any other device and everything works in all devices in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

- I'm running out of ideas as to what could be the problem??
- I work with commercial apps and they shouldn't have bugs or crashes.

*I have an app on Google play since a year or so, but had to update it to API34 because the old ActionBar tabs/ViewPager with Fragments are deprecated and I to use the new Toolbar/ TabLayout/ViewPager2 and ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter approach.*

- A pretty job to do
- **Works great in Android studio, the app runs with better performance (it's better Java code)**
- Works well with all emulators and all my physical devices with Android Studio by cable

**So I'm updating in Google play with the new bundle version**

- Works great, the app runs with better performance
- **Works well with all my physical devices stand alone** and all emulators (with Google play)
- **Except in a Samsung J6 phone (SM-J600FN) that crashes when I open the work-file.**

The crash is in my C (NDK 25.1.8937393) code where I was able to follow the crash with Logcat in Android studio

- **The strange thing is that it crashes in completely innocent loops** where it reads correct values out of structures and write in the same structures updated data (like int and void*), there is simply nothing wrong with the code
- Even the same code has been running in a previous loop with the same data without any problems
- If you run another working file, it crashes in another completely undramatic loop, guaranteed without any program errors. Same type of crash but in different places of the code.
- The feeling is that it is that the entire NDK heap crashes in the phone, like it is evaporated?

**Logcat dump**

> 2024-02-14 02:28:35.383 17422-17422 [myapp]                 se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]          D  CheckActive -1 / 1 - 1 1010

> 2024-02-14 02:28:35.383 17422-17422 [myapp]                 se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]          D  CheckActive -1 / 1 - 1 1020

> 2024-02-14 02:28:35.383 17422-17422 [myapp].Rosett          se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]          W  0xebadde09 skipped times: 0

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.012 17422-17422 [myapp].Rosett          se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]          W  0xebadde09 skipped times: 0

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.012 17422-17422 libc                    se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]          A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x594d2d59 in tid 17422 ([myapp].[myapp]), pid 17422 ([myapp].[myapp])

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.217 18639-18639 DEBUG                   pid-18639                            A  pid: 17422, tid: 17422, name: [myapp].[myapp]  > > >  se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp] <<<

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.994 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #00 pc 004a1c76  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/base.apk!libAndroid[myapp].so (offset 0x4174000) (LListGetFirstRecordData+20) (BuildId: 19096f2d2d09e4b8936ad2ee91916033257eda0e)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.994 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #01 pc 004ac061  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/base.apk!libAndroid[myapp].so (offset 0x4174000) (CheckActive+1012) (BuildId: 19096f2d2d09e4b8936ad2ee91916033257eda0e)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.994 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #02 pc 004b4205  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/base.apk!libAndroid[myapp].so (offset 0x4174000) (TabOptimisation+448) (BuildId: 19096f2d2d09e4b8936ad2ee91916033257eda0e)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.994 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #03 pc 00451e93  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/base.apk!libAndroid[myapp].so (offset 0x4174000) (InitMainView+206) (BuildId: 19096f2d2d09e4b8936ad2ee91916033257eda0e)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.994 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #04 pc 004520a5  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/base.apk!libAndroid[myapp].so (offset 0x4174000) (Java_se_[mydomain]_[myapp]_JniManagement_InitMainView+316) (BuildId: 19096f2d2d09e4b8936ad2ee91916033257eda0e)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.994 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #05 pc 0001fc33  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/oat/arm/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+162)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.995 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #13 pc 003432f6  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/oat/arm/base.vdex (se.[mydomain].[myapp].v0.j+58)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.995 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #16 pc 0033f494  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/oat/arm/base.vdex (se.[mydomain].[myapp].JniManagement.f+284)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.995 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #19 pc 002f8172  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/oat/arm/base.vdex (n5.r.f+490)

> 2024-02-14 02:28:37.995 18639-18639 DEBUG                   crash_dump32                         A        #22 pc 00340228  /data/app/se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]-9JjQztNsGJZagQkfzm3yRA==/oat/arm/base.vdex (se.[mydomain].[myapp].MainActivity.onActivityResult+680)

> ---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (18641) for package se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp] ----------------------------

> 2024-02-14 02:28:39.814  2880-3994  BufferQueueProducer     surfaceflinger                       E  [Application Error: se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp]#0] disconnect: not connected (req=1)

> ---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (17422) for package se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp] ----------------------------

> ---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (18641) for package se.[mydomain].[myapp].[myapp] ----------------------------

**Design**

The program is built with a complete functionality in NDK with interfaces for commands and a virtual screen. The working files are opened and sent to the NDK module to create the full-function virtual display. Next, the monitor is copied into the Java fragment, a LinearLayout with a number of TextView per line (like an Excel sheet).

- We are talking about C code that works great in all other Android devices, in the corresponding applications in iOS and in Winapi.

**The question is why is the app crashing in this device?**

- My TabA SM-T590 tablet has no problem Kernel 3.18.124 while J6 has Kernel 3.18.140 (basically the same operating system)
- No other apps have issues with crashes in J6 device?
- There is in the J6 plenty of disk space, 6.4Gb, main memory 1.5Gb and the app consumes about 200Mb and at worst 40% processing power (J6 in Android Studio in debug mode)
- I've tried to find other background apps that could interfere with the whole environment, but nothing stands out?
- Yes, it's my 85 year old dad's old cell phone (which I changed because he has dementia and mom's cell phone has USBC and they destroy the contacts if they are different).
- Yes, it's dad's gmail address still in the mobile phone (his Google account) and mine (my Google account) in all the other devices that I installed from Google play. But different Google accounts can't make a difference???

I'm running out of ideas as to what could be the problem??

Comment: 40% processing power means 40% of one CPU core or 40% of the system? If it is the system you should consider other problem sources like an old battery that can not provide enough power to the CPU which causes defects in the code processing. I would connect the phone to a charger and retry. Or check the phone with a benchmark tool it it sill works stable even with higher COU usage.

Comment: Oh, thanks for a constructive comment. In general, the app is not performance demanding more than it does a job to read and process a text work file. The 40% is the peak reading the file and have worked with far worse old Android, never failed else. The phone is charging while I do the logcat analyse (cable is connected). But the  benchmark tool suggestion I find very interesting. Yes there might be something wrong with the unit, and I can't make factory reset because I can't destroy the installation for now because it is used. Any suggestion of a  benchmark tool?

Comment: One thing I wonder is if anything connected to a specific Google login account setup, can make any difference? Or shall I scrap that theme from the problem search?